# There is an observation on the eigenvalues of the sum of a kind of special Hermitian matrices. How to prove it?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ belong to a kind of special hermitian matrices, which have the following properties:

1. $A$ and $B$ contain only one negative eigenvalue.
2. the negative eigenvalue and the second-largest positive eigenvalue are opposite to each other.
3. $\operatorname{trace}(A) = \operatorname{trace}(B)= 1$.

Let
$$
C=\alpha A+(1-\alpha)B,\quad \alpha \in [0,1].
$$
Then, we can find that the absolute value of the minimum eigenvalue of $C$ is always less than the second-largest positive eigenvalue of $C$ (just like an upper bound).

Can this observation be proved?

Comment: This does not make it clear how it fits into qa-quantum-algebra or quantum-groups.

Comment: oh, my fault, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look correct even for diagonal matrices.